# How to get memory address in C and output it?

Tags: c, pointers, bit-manipulation

I need to get memory address and bits of index then I need to output index of the memory address. Can anyone help?

Comment: I tried to do with array but I could not get it done..

Answer (score 18):

Given any variable in C, you can get its address using the "address-of" operator `&`:

```
int x;
int* addressOfX = &x;
```

You can print out addresses using the `%p` specifier in `printf`:

```
printf("%p\n", &x); // Print address of x
```

To access individual bits of an integer value, you can use the bitwise shifting operators, along with bitwise AND, to shift the bit you want to the proper position and then to mask out the other bits.  For example, to get the 5th bit of `x`, you can write

```
int x;
int fifthBit = (x >> 4) & 0x1;
```

This shifts down the number 4 bits, leaving the fifth bit in the LSB spot.  ANDing this value with 1 (which has a 1 bit in the lowest spot and 0 bits everywhere else) masks out the other bits and returns the value.  For example:

```
int x = 31; // 11111
prtinf("%d\n", (x >> 4) & 0x1); // Prints 1
```

Comment: +1 Much more helpful than "read about pointers", whether solid advice or not.

Comment: The thing is that address is provided by user... I was planning to get it in array but I could not figure that out...

Comment: @TipiTip- You can't read arbitrary memory addresses given by the user; your OS will almost certainly kill the program if it did.  If you have a reason to think that this is safe, you can typecast an integer containing a location to a pointer to raw memory by writing `char* rawMemoryPtr = (char*)myIntegerAddress;`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me ;)

```
  // uses :: head
  // ----------------------------------------------
     #include <stdio.h>
  // ----------------------------------------------


  // func :: main
  // ----------------------------------------------
     int main()
     {
        void *fooz = "bar";
        char addr[64];

        sprintf(addr, "%p", &fooz);

        // do some stuff with `addr`, or not :)
        puts(addr);

        return 0;
     }
  // ----------------------------------------------
```

Prints out something like: ~> 0x7ffdfb91d698